# How can i get this number set to be recooperated from a product sum?

Tags: mathematica

W==a(x)=2*(W* x)/41;

I'm attempting to make a new type of compression algorithm. A rubber band ball type.

I'm trying to make a software that extracts, from that formula, the secret volumes of number sets within. By taking the the opposite formula, b(x) i should get the answer. But unfortunately, i dont. I have to search 0-255(+1). Through the first generation the numbers would be like as follows
(W starts at 1)
    a(82*1)==2
    b(2/1)==82

I need the numbers reappear for me. How can I do this without cheating?

Q: What is the best `if` statement to get my numbers to reappear?

[My code as is right now.](http://www.ideone.com/mZKttO)

Comment: This question and its associated answer need a lot of help. I can't tell what the question is about or how it connects to computational science. The answer doesn't use a single symbol in common with the question.

Comment: @onex4: Welcome to SciComp! It's not clear what your question is about, or how it relates to computational science. I am going to close the question for now. If you would like it reopened, please revise it to clarify the meaning of your question, and to show how it relates to computational science.

Comment: @geoffoxberry sorry, trying to be subtle so it isnt stolen.

Comment: What is not stolen? The question? This is a site of questions and answers, you need to provide a (clear) question.

Comment: I do apologize. This is something ive spent countless hours on. Probably 120 in 7 days. The question is, what is a good `if` statement for looking through 1-256?

Comment: Ive compares b to a in each way i could. I get back some really superfluous answers and they dont congeal. Id love to be done with this. Thats why im seeking help. Thanks.